# How to add RAID5 to existing crypto-LVM?

Tags: linux, lvm, encryption, raid5

I recently installed Debian Wheezy and let the installer guide partition the disk using a whole partition with encryption (LVM). Later on I've added four disks and setup RAID5 on them (using `mdadm`).

My question is: How do I add the RAID-set to the existing crypto-lvm, making the RAID encrypted as well?

Comment: LVM has internal RAID5 capabilities, you might try to research that avenue rather than mixing block device management schemes (not that there's anything wrong with that, just involves one extra thing in the configuration).

Comment: Found this while working the old google machine: http://www.olearycomputers.com/ll/linux_mirrors.html . It's comparing mdadm raid to LVM raid.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the RAID doesn't have any files on it yet;

you'd format it using LUKS for encryption:

```
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/md42
```

then you'd open the LUKS container

```
crytpsetup luksOpen /dev/md42 luks42
```

if you want to use LVM with that, you'd turn it into a Physical Volume:

```
pvcreate /dev/mapper/luks42
```

and if you want to add that to your existing volume group

```
vgextend yourvg /dev/mapper/luks42
```

and then you can create some new LVs

```
lvcreate -L42G -n fourtytwo yourvg
```

and then you'd put some filesystem on that

```
mkfs.ext42 /dev/yourvg/fourtytwo
```

and then mount it

```
mkdir /mnt/42
mount /dev/yourvg/fourtytwo /mnt/42
```

and so on and so forth